# How to run an obfs4 bridge?

Tags: censorship, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy, obfs4, obfs4proxy

I want to help censored users. How can I run an obfs4 (Pluggable Transport) bridge on a Debian-like GNU/Linux machine?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Tor Project's official guide [is available here](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/). It has instructions on how to set up an obfs4 bridge for several platforms, including [Debian and Ubuntu](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/). Don't forget to make sure that your OR port *and* your obfs4 port must be publicly reachable. Tor automatically tests its OR port but it currently (as of August 2019) does not test its obfs4 port. You can use [this scanning tool](https://bridges.torproject.org/scan/) to make sure that your obfs4 port is publicly reachable.

**Step 0**: Follow [this guide](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) to setup the official package repository, and install Tor.

**Step 1**: Edit your `sources.list` to add `obfs4proxy` repository:

*Note: you can skip this step if you're running Debian stable (jessie) or more recent.*

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org obfs4proxy main
```

**Step 2**: Install `obfs4proxy`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obfs4proxy
```

**Step 3**: Edit your `torrc` config file, usually located at `/etc/tor/torrc`

```
#Bridge config
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 9001
BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ExtORPort auto
#set the Nickname and Contact info
ContactInfo <your-contact-info>
Nickname <pick-a-nickname>
```

**Step 4**: Restart Tor

```
$ sudo service tor restart
```

**Step 5**: Check the logs and confirm the `ORPort` is reachable and the `obfs4proxy` is working.

```
$ sudo tail -F /var/log/tor/log
```

You should see something like this:

```
[notice] Registered server transport 'obfs4' at '[::]:46396'
[notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
[notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
[notice] Now checking whether ORPort <redacted>:9001 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
[notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.
```

Comment: I would argue for specifying a port number rather than using "auto". That way you know what to allow in your firewall settings.

Comment: The "ExtORPort auto" above is fine -- the extended ORPort is for local connections, and you don't need to open anything in your external firewall. That said, if you want to pick your obfs4 port number, you could add a torrc line like "ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:52812". But diversity of obfs4 ports is actually really important, so I'd argue against any instructions that will lead people to using the same port.

Comment: Extended ORPort is the port used by extended transport plugins to listen to inbound connections, not for Tor to connect to such plugins. The network connection between Tor and extended plugins is random and there's no setting to specify them, ALAIK, and each plugin uses its own port. If we have obfs3 and obfs4 enabled, they use 2 ports.

Comment: In example, if we use `ORPort 8443` and `ExtORPort 443`, normal/unobfuscated Tor connections will come to port 8443, and connections using both obfs3 and obfs4 obfuscation will come to port 443. I don't see why ORPort can be set and ExtORPort should be random. ExtORPort *is* used by outside world and *needs* to be forwarded on router. For guard relays, it's also more helpful to use a HTTPS port to help make you look like an average website in the world, than a whacky port that will probably be blocked on Tor user's network.

Answer (score 4):

Great explanation, it helped me a lot. Like to add the following; These days I do not see a lot of obfs4 traffic yet. If you want to publish as an obfs3 AND obfs4 bridge relay you can change the line

```
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
```

to

```
ServerTransportPlugin obfs3,obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
```

You only need to install obfs4 as mentioned in the post above. obfs4 is backwards compatible with obfs3.

When you start up your bridge, you will see something like this in your logfile;

```
Registered server transport 'obfs3' at '[::]:41234'
Registered server transport 'obfs4' at '[::]:44321'
```

Leave your ExtORPort set to auto for  diversity reasons. I have a firewall enabled on my Debian bridge with very restrictive port settings. I had to make port forwards for the given obfs ports in iptables (easy with gufw) as well as in my hardware (internet-)firewall to make things work. So I am not so sure that the ExORPort is for local connections only as mentioned by Rodger (please let me know if I am wrong here). The obfs3 and obfs4 transport ports Tor chooses for you will be cached, so after booting your bridge you keep the same ports. Hope this helps.

Tor needs bridges, be a bridge if you can!