# Optimal configuration for an obfs4 bridge

Tags: configuration, bridge, censorship, pluggable-transports, obfs4proxy

In response to the blocking of Tor in even more countries and organisations, I decided to set up a (private) bridge. I would like the bridge to:

- be accessible to users with strict outgoing connection filtering (in particular, blocking of access to non-standard ports)
- be as difficult to discover as possible (consider scanning of known ports for Tor protocol)

What would be the configuration of the bridge to best address these goals?

Namely:

1. What numbers to choose for OR and obfs4proxy ports?
2. Does opening a DIR port on a bridge make sense, and if yes, on which port?
3. Which ports to forward on the router?
4. Does using IPv6 provide any benefit over just IPv4?

[How to run an obfs4 bridge?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/how-to-run-an-obfs4-bridge) provides some highlights but does not exactly answer the questions I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What numbers to choose for OR and obfs4proxy ports?

For an obfs4 bridge I'd recommend:

1. Picking a low numbered port that's used by a common service for `obfs4` (it takes a few extra steps to allow `obfs4` to bind to low ports) might help *some* user (and may *hinder* others, e.g. if their DPI reasons: "I know that `obfs4` traffic definitely isn't the service that normally runs on port 443".)
2. Picking a randomly chosen high numbered port that *isn't* used by any common services for the `ORPort` to make it more difficult to detect by someone performing internet wide scans on common ports. (e.g. `python2 -c 'import random;print random.randint(1025,65535)'`)

I'd strongly recommend that you implement 2, but 1 is more of an open question. By default `obfs4proxy` will pick a random high numbered port for itself.

> Does opening a DIR port on a bridge make sense, and if yes, on which port?

No, the client *will* use you as a directory guard but this communication is done over the `obfs4` or `OR` connection. This *doesn't* require exposing a `DirPort` and exposing one is just adding more potential for your bridge to be detected as a bridge from some adversary scanning for bridges.

> Does using IPv6 provide any benefit over just IPv4?

It will allow users who are on IPv6-only connections to use your bridge. Anecdotally, since IPv6 isn't widely adopted *some* (of the crappier) DPI *might* have a tougher time censoring IPv6.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering about your example of `obfs4` on port 443 hindering some users; `obfs4` spec says: _obfs4 offers protection against passive Deep Packet Inspection machines that expect the obfs4 protocol_.

Comment: Yet another question: would it make sense to hide the `ORport` (by not forwarding it on the router) and setting `AssumeReachable` to 1?

Comment: `obfs4` looks like random data, if it sees random data on port 443 it could tell that it is not HTTPS/TLS traffic (since no TLS handshake was observed) and block it. It might expect strange traffic on higher number ports (some unknown peer-to-peer protocol). I don't have solid answers for those.

Comment: If you're distributing a private bridge (e.g. one that isn't given out by BridgeDB and is handed out by you manually) then it absolutely makes sense to block the ORPort. But I believe that BridgeDB will want to use the ORPort, it's expected that an ORPort is exposed, so it may result in BridgeDB considering your bridge down and not distributing it.